# How to pass form-urlencoded data in GET request with SWIFT 5

Tags: asp.net, swift, xcode, api

I'm using Swift 5 and attempting to get an access token from an API I'm developing using asp.net MVC. With Postman I set my request to GET, pass in some information in the body, and I get back an access token.

In XCode when I try this it gives me the error: "GET method must not have a body."

My Code:

```
func GetToken(email: String, password: String) {
        let dataToSend = [
            "grant_type": "password",
            "username": email,
            "password": password
        ]

        let newData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataToSend, options: [])

        var request = URLRequest(url: getNewTokenURL)
        request.httpMethod = "Get"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = newData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(TokenResponse.self, from: data)

                self.userToken = myData.accessToken

            }
            catch {

            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

How do I perform the GET request with the data I need to send to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests don't have a body. Parameters in a GET request are passed along with it's url as query parameters.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/getExample?sampleParam=sampleValue&anotherParam=anotherValue")
```

Edit: Also you need to give method in all caps. Since GET is the default you didn't have an issue.

Also if you are sure that the data is being passed as JSON then the method should be a POST method for that you just need to set the method of the request to POST as follows:

```
request.method = "POST"
```

Note: It's case sensitive.

Comment: But isn't data passed with query parameters insecure? I'm passing an email and password.

Comment: And you think JSON encoding makes it secure? You'll need encryption to make it secure. That is not the point here if, you want to pass parameters as JSON then you need a post method.